# Why is this ("is just publishing on github enough") question offtopic? Where should I ask it?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, on-topic-definition

I asked [the question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/149534/is-just-publishing-my-program-on-github-enough-for-it-to-be-searchable-for-users), but instead of answers/comments got only downvotes and close votes. I though programmers.SE is just right place for this question because of, being not technical (so SO is not good option), it is about what programmers should do with their projects.

What is the problem with that question? Where should I ask it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My problem with the question (I haven't down-voted but did vote to close - obviously) is that it's not a real question.

You ramble on for most of the question and only in the last sentence actually come up with a question that seems more suited for Meta Super User than Programmers.

What **exactly** are you trying to ask?

Comment: Whether I need additional actions (apart for publishing and improving the project) to be useful for other users.

Comment: Answers are expected to be like "No. Just publish. If your project is actually useful, users will find it. Some maintainer will create a package if needed" or "Yes, you should find where to put info about your program. Providing this, that and that things is also necessary, or users will not find your program".

Comment: @Vi0: Couched that way, your question seems like a crystal-ball question.  How would we know?  Your utility might be the best thing since sliced bread and have wide applicability, in which case simply publishing may be enough, and people will beat down your door to get the utility.  On the other hand, your utility might be some highly obscure bit of functional programming code that only computer scientists and mathematicians would understand, in which case you need publication in a specialized journal to get the word out.  I repeat: *how would we know this?*

Comment: tl;dr *We are not marketing experts.*

Comment: I though that there may be some guideline (which I don't know about) what to do for various cases.

Comment: Nobody knows.  That's the black magic that is marketing; you have to try things and see what works.  By the time something works and we can tell you it works, the public has gotten tired of it, and you have to try something new.

Comment: The only thing that we know for sure works is *relevance.*  Relevance is the thing Sergey and Brin built a multi-billion dollar empire on.